# Marshmallow only displaying https sites

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

The network connection on my Nexus 6 with Android Marshmallow (rooted) is messed up, and right now the only pattern I can see is that only pages with HTTPS are displaying. I can supply a bug report.

Comment: A Log would be helpful here, and any more info would also be useful. E.g. Does this happen with the default browser or does it happen with other browsers (Chrome, Firefox, UC mini etc.). Any extra info will help us narrow down the problem and help you solve it.

Comment: @Matt0711 This happens with everything, even app's like Imgur or SoundCloud. I also tried Firefox (since I thought the HTTPS everywhere plugin would help)

Comment: Can you supply a [tag:logcat]

Comment: Did this happen recently or since you bought it? Or was there a moment when you didn't have this problem? If it was, can you remember what did you do to the device at that moment? Does this happen on WiFi and mobile data?

Comment: I have no idea if it happens with data, since my plan doesn't include data. The problem started a little while after upgrading to Marshmallow. Right now I'm trying to upload a logcat, but it'll take me a while

Answer (score -1):

Don't know why, but changing the SIM card seems to have fixed it.